# Second by second stock data from Bloomberg API (or anywhere else that is free) into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: equities, programming, bloomberg, currency

I need to compile stock price data for ADR and ORD pairs (and the currency between them) into a Pandas dataframe. My initial plan was use Python's requests library and a free Rapid API account to get data from the Bloomberg API, the code for which I've attached below. The issue with this is that the time intervals seem to be 5 minutes at the fastest, and I need much faster. (The "MY RAPID API KEY" is removed because you must create a free account to get a key. I'm already near the limit of requests my account can make for the month so I can't give it out, sorry for the inconvenience)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

def extract_ticks(interval="d1"):
    url="https://bloomberg-market-and-financial-news.p.rapidapi.com/market/get-chart"
    querystring = {"interval":interval,"id":"dge:ln"}
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "bloomberg-market-and-financial-news.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "MY RAPID API KEY"
        }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    json_d = response.json()
    return json_d
#Get year to date data ytd
json_d = extract_ticks()
print(json_d) 

# Write the data to json file
import json
with open("dge_ytd.json","w") as fp:
    json.dump(json_d,fp)

import pandas as pd
import datetime
with open("dge_ytd.json","r") as fp:
     json_d = json.load(fp)
 ticks_d = json_d['result']['DGE:LN']['ticks']
 df = pd.DataFrame(ticks_d)
 df['Close'] = df['close']
 df['Date'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
 df = df.set_index('time')
 data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
 data

#creating a separate dataset
 new_data = data[['Date','Close']]
 index = range(0,len(new_data))
 new_data['index']=index
 new_data=new_data.set_index('index')
 new_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(new_data.Date,format='%Y-%m-%d')
 new_data
```

[image: Jupyter Output]

This code does great work for the formatting I need and storage of the Dataframe, and the Bloomberg API is very easy to use. My school has a Bloomberg Terminal, which I've never used before. Can I get faster time intervals using the Terminal license, or will I need to find a different data source? If so, what data sources can I use that I can get for very cheap and how can I get the data into a pandas df?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if there's any clarifying information I can provide in the comments; this is my first question so I'm hoping I followed the correct formatting procedure (I couldn't copy in Jupyter output without columns getting mangled together)

Comment: The terminal will not allow you to get such data - Bloomberg is quite good when it comes to restricting access to these things.

Comment: @rubikscube09 does that mean that any faster data from Bloomberg would be past a massive pay wall? If so, are there other finance APIs that are similar at all?

Comment: What frequency do you require? Minute level ? Seconds? Tick level?

Comment: @ColeMcMahon-Gioeli most likely yes. There are quite a few ticker data providers out there, at a variety of frequencies.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I need at least minute level, but preferably second level. I don't need anything sub-second level. What ticker data providers would you recommend?

Comment: Alphavantage gets you Minute level data, or maybe Quandl. But I do not know whether they cover your tickers- you could give them a try

Comment: Finam has 1m bars, and even tick-level data. Round lots and regular trading session only: https://www.finam.ru/profile/akcii-usa-bats/airbnb-inc_abnb/export/?market=25&em=2205924&token=&code=ABNB&apply=0&df=1&mf=2&yf=2021&from=01.02.2021&dt=7&mt=2&yt=2021&to=07.02.2021&p=2&f=ABNB_210201_210207&e=.csv&cn=ABNB&dtf=4&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstimever=0&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=1&at=1&fsp=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use Alphavantage and inquire a student offer, that gives you more calls per minute and more calls per month. You only have to have a student mail account and confirm the purposes of your endeavour.